# Overwrite a matrix defined with zeros

Tags: matlab, time-series, data-analysis, tensor, covariance

I have a tensor (L, L, H) ppa (where Area is L* L, and the height H is the number of time steps in a timeseries) and a vector naut (size H). I need to do the covariance between the timeseries in the tensor, so the all the columns, whose elements are: the 1st element is the element (i,j) in the 1st area, the 2nd is the element (i,j) in the second area and the to the H-th area, forming the tensor.
So, I reshape the tensor to have L*L columns of H elements to covariate with my vector.

```
ppa = reshape(paut, Area, H)';  
Naut=naut';
my_cov = zeros(Area,1);
```

from the covariance matrix that I get from doing the covariance of every column with Naut, I want to take just the element (1,2) because it is symmetric and I only need the covariance.

```
   for i=1:H 
        %cov matrix between the i-column and NAO 
        cov_tmp = cov(ppa(:,i), Naut); 
        %extracting the covariance element that I need from the covariance 
        %matrix 
        my_cov(i) = cov_tmp(1,2); 
    end
```

then I overwrite the vector my_cov to get a vector in which I have a series of covariance.

```
% if you want back a 120x120 matrix, just reshape 
my_cov = reshape(my_cov,L,L);
```

the problem is that the vector `my_cov` keeps containing all zeros so the overwriting doesn't work.

Comment: Is LxL the same as H? I think you intended to loop over LxL elements, and take a vector of length L from the matrix each time?

Comment: LxL has not the same size of H, but I want to compare every column of data made of element (i,j) in (LxL)i area, with i that has size H , with NAUT whose size is H too